# Why is this query slower when used in a view?

Tags: sql-server, performance, view

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT LASTNAME,NAME,STREET,PHONE,ID_CARD 
FROM PHONES1..TVPHONES  
UNION ALL

SELECT LASTNAME,NAME,STREET,PHONE,ID_CARD 
FROM PHONES2..TVPHONES 
UNION ALL

SELECT LASTNAME,NAME,STREET,PHONE,ID_CARD 
FROM PHONES3..TVPHONES
) q 
WHERE ID_CARD = 'B5XXXXXXX'
```

This query takes 0.03 seconds to finish,  but if I convert this into a view and perform the same search:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[BTPHONES]  
AS

 SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT LASTNAME,NAME,STREET,PHONE,ID_CARD 
    FROM PHONES1..TVPHONES  
    UNION ALL

    SELECT LASTNAME,NAME,STREET,PHONE,ID_CARD 
    FROM PHONES2..TVPHONES 
    UNION ALL

    SELECT LASTNAME,NAME,STREET,PHONE,ID_CARD 
    FROM PHONES3..TVPHONES
    ) q 

GO

-- ------------------------

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.BTPHONES
WHERE ID_CARD = 'B5XXXXXXX'
```

takes about 3 minutes!! Why is it taking so long?

Plan01:

[image: Plan 01]

Plan02:

[image: Plan 02]

Comment: Did you compare actual execution plans?

Comment: I ran the CTRL + L. In the first case, the cost is 0% in most parts of the query. In contrast, in the second case, the cost varies from 40-60%

Comment: @csotelo You should post that as an answer

Comment: Also, the queries are not equivalent - the top just returns all the results, the bottom has to pick an arbitrary TOP 1. Why are you using TOP 1 without an ORDER BY?

Comment: I have attached part of plans

Comment: Adding `TOP 1` can change the plan substantially (enouraging non blocking operators such as nested loops)

Comment: You are right. If I remove the TOP operator changes the response time. But if I would get a certain amount of records, as I can avoid the slow?

Answer (score 0):

The second case is equivalent to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT LASTNAME,NAME,STREET,PHONE,ID_CARD 
    FROM PHONES1..TVPHONES  
    UNION ALL

    SELECT LASTNAME,NAME,STREET,PHONE,ID_CARD 
    FROM PHONES2..TVPHONES 
    UNION ALL

    SELECT LASTNAME,NAME,STREET,PHONE,ID_CARD 
    FROM PHONES3..TVPHONES
  ) q
)
WHERE ID_CARD = 'B5XXXXXXX'
```

The optimiser probably doesn't realise that it could apply the where clause to each of the inner selects. Instead it creates the union of the entire tables and then does a full scan on the result to apply the where clause.